# How to hide labels, entries, and pickers when radio button is clicked

Tags: c#, xamarin

Does anyone know why my code doesn't work?

I'm trying to hide labels, entries, and pickers when a certain radio button is clicked but for some reason it's not working.

My goal is to have different labels and entries show up when the user clicks any of the two radio buttons.

and yes, my Radio Buttons are grouped.

[image]

```
        private void DeliveryRadioBtn_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DeliveryRadioBtn.IsChecked == true)
        {

        }
       else if (PickUpRadioBtn.IsChecked == true)
        {
            AddressLbl.IsEnabled = false;
            StreetLbl.IsEnabled = false;
            UserStreetEntry.IsEnabled = false;
            CityLbl.IsEnabled = false;
            UserCityEntry.IsEnabled = false;
            StateLbl.IsEnabled = false;
            userStatePicker.IsEnabled = false;
            ZipLbl.IsEnabled = false;
            UserZipEntry.IsEnabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: use `javascript` instead of depending on code behind.

Answer (score 3):

to hide an element

```
myElement.IsVisible = false;
```

what you are doing is disabling it, not hiding it